# C# - Port Mapping with .Net Core 5.0

Tags: c#, .net, networking, upnp, asp.net-core-5.0

### Expected Outcome

I'm attempting to make an ASP.NET Core 5.0 application using Kestrel, and I would like to auto port forward the server's port.

### Package

I'm currently using the [`OpenNat.Core`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Open.NAT.Core/) package.  I have also tried the regular [`OpenNat`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Open.Nat/) and the same issue arises.

### Issue

When port forwarding, the program says it has mapped everything correctly and the map even shows when listing all mapped ports on my router. Yet, when I attempt to view its status via [CanYouSeeMe.org](https://canyouseeme.org) it returns a timed out error, and I am unable to access the server outside the network.

### What I've Tried

1. I thought that the port mapping might have been opening after the server started, so I manually opened the port and then restarted the Kestrel server.
2. I made sure that my router supported UPnP

   - I also have a Synology NAS that I port forward from, and it works just fine.
3. I had a friend use ZenMap to check the port.

   - The port shows that it's filtered but not open (and no service was specified).

### Code

```cs
using Open.Nat;
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
...
        public static async Task OpenPort(int port, string description)
        {
            try
            {
                
                NatDiscoverer discoverer = new NatDiscoverer();
                CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource(10000);
                NatDevice device = await discoverer.DiscoverDeviceAsync(PortMapper.Upnp, cts);
                Mapping map = new(Protocol.Tcp, port, port, description);
                await device.CreatePortMapAsync(map);
                Console.WriteLine($"Created {map}");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind my firewall was blocking the application.  I was able to dynamically add a firewall rule to fix the issue.